# In languages with robust case systems, such as Latin, Russian, and Finnish, is there a case in which appositives commonly occur?

Tags: syntax, morphology

In English appositive constructions, noun phrases can be juxtaposed to convey the fact that they are co-referential.    "I, Don Quixote," "John, the baker," "the art-object, a bronzed umbrella," and "the other dog, the dangerous one" are all appositive constructions.

In languages with robust case-systems, such as Latin, Russian, and Finnish, do appositive constructions typically each comprise noun phrases in the same case?

Or is there typically a case in such languages that marks a noun phrase as apposite another one?   For instance, could genitive be used in this manner to create phrases like "dog-NOM  sighthound-GEN" to mean "the dog, a sighthound"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Latin, and similarly in other languages, the apposite is in the same case as its antecedent, for example "Ego, Claudius" (I, Claudius, both nominative), "Me, Claudium, vidit" (he saw me, Claudius, both accusative.)